# Can't get the browser to read my CSS

Tags: css

Can't work out why this code is not working:

CSS then corresponding HTML:

```css
.intro {
  border: 5px
  border-color: rgb(0,0,255);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
   <p>writing</p>
   <p>writing</p>
</div>
```

No variation seems to work, and I have checked this site, W3C, and seem to be writing the code correctly in the CSS file, but it just is not translating to the browser (Chrome).

Comment: Run your CSS through a CSS validator such as that at https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to end one of your CSS lines with a semicolon.

```css
.intro {
 border: 5px;
 border-color: rgb(0,0,255);
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
   <p>writing</p>
   <p>writing</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I made that change and it still does not seem to work. Even in the snippet, it put the text centre, but did not add a border.

Comment: You went to all the trouble of creating a snippet, but then you didn't check that the snippet actually worked. No border is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I registered just now to answer your question,you forgot to add this code in your CSS:

```css
.intro{border-style:solid;}
```

border-style is default hidden,you forgot that so you can't see the border.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) If you do not assign a value,The default value is defined for it. default value for `border-style` is `none`, so you can't see result.
>
> 2) A CSS declaration always ends with a semicolon(`;`).

**Change :**

```
 .intro {
     border: 5px   <-------------------
     border-color: rgb(0,0,255);
     text-align: center;
    }
```

**To :**

```
.intro {
     border: 5px solid;   <-------------------
     border-color: rgb(0,0,255);
     text-align: center;
    }
```

**or**

```
.intro {
     border: 5px;
     border-style: solid;   <----------- Or other Value.
     border-color: rgb(0,0,255);
     text-align: center;
    }
```